# Angular: ContentChild is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm using Angular 5 and trying to create some kind of dynamic component.

I have a simple directive, `MyColumnDef` (with the selector `[myColumnDef]`). There is nothing special about it. I'm using it in:

**parent.compontent.html**:

```
<div>
  <my-table>
    <ng-template myColumnDef>
      Lorem ipsum.
    </ng-template>
  </my-table>
</div>
```

**my-table.component.html**:

```
<div>
  Something:
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="temp"></ng-container>
</div>
```

In **my-table.component.ts**:

```
 @ContentChild(MyColumnDef, {read: TemplateRef}) temp;
```

This should show the `'Lorem ipsum.'` text, but there is nothing, actually the `temp` is `undefined` (according to `console.log` in `ngAfterViewInit`), and I don't know why. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't put the directive in its own module's `exports` array.